# Why doesn't println() read my package that I've created?

Tags: java

I've written a program and it works but not the way I wish it to be. So I made a package and when I am trying to put my package into my `print()` statement it says symbol cannot be found but I imported it at the top.

This is the code I have so far:

```
//Program is is beng made to graph students incorrect entries
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;
import utils.*;

public class Histo 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner textFile = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter integers that are less than 25, one per line, hit control + z, when finished");

        int[]scores = new int[26];

        while( textFile.hasNext()) 
        {
            int startStar = textFile.nextInt();
            scores[startStar]++;

        }

        for ( int stars = 0; stars < scores.length; stars++)
        {

            if (scores[stars] != 0)
            {
                System.out.print( stars + " ");
                for ( int n = 1; n <= scores[stars]; n++)
                {
                    System.out.print("*"  +  TextKit.lineOfStars);

                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your package or your class? Also I do not see an import for `TextKit`

Comment: @Sakura.Mom Do import the package which contains `TextKit` class first. Then, check the code again. It'll definitely work!

Comment: I used import java.util.*; to retrieve my TextKit package but I I will give it a try thank you so much

Comment: Why do you think `TextKit` is in [java.util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html)? It isn't, as you see when you click on the link and read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you refer to the class `utils.TextKit` as specified by https://wpollock.com/AJava/TextKit/TextKit.java

It has a static method `lineOfStars` that wants an integer as parameter.

Therefore, I guess you need to do this:

```
....
if (scores[stars] != 0)
{
  System.out.print(stars + " ");
  System.out.println(TextKit.lineOfStars(scores[stars]));
}
```

Or even more simple:

```
....
if (scores[stars] != 0)
  System.out.println(stars + " " + TextKit.lineOfStars(scores[stars]));
```